# Why this query is giving me the same result in each column? The data of 26th and 31st are different

Tags: mysql, join

Why this query is giving me the same result in each column? The data of 26th and 31st are different.:

```
select v26.total_vaccinations, v31.total_vaccinations 
from vaccination_data_26th v26 
    natural join vaccination_data_31st v31;
```

Comment: No where clean clause? No on clause to specify the join?

Comment: Because you are querying 2 seperate tables as if the records were all on one table

Comment: Thank you. It worked now with this: select v26.total_vaccinations, v31.total_vaccinations 
from vaccination_data_26th v26, vaccination_data_31st v31
where v26.country = v31.country;

Can you tell me how to do it using Natural join?

Comment: [ask] [mre] [help]

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have not told us how a JOIN would be made between the 2 tables. My guess is there is no real connections, they look like exactly the same data but for a different day. Not the best database design for this, but ..

So I suggest the use of a UNION

```
select v26.total_vaccinations from vaccination_data_26th
UNION
select v31.total_vaccinations from vaccination_data_31st
```

Or so that you can identify what number comes from which date

```
select '26th', v26.total_vaccinations from vaccination_data_26th
UNION
select '31st', v31.total_vaccinations from vaccination_data_31st
```